# Multiple Opening Paths

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have an application that can launch/new up a form(lets call it QuickNoteForm) from many different actions. It can launch the form from many different tabs and mostly are launched thru buttons all over my application.

I basically want to track where it was launched from, ie I need to track its Launch Path.

What would be a good approach to implement this. I was thinking to enclose this as a property that gets set via the constructor of the QuickNoteForm. I want to track from which action this form got launched from.

This is a windows forms application and not a asp.net app.

thanks.

Comment: The article/question above might be more related to reflection, and assemblies. I should clarify the question and keep to WindowsForms and communicate within a large application.

Comment: I listed some ideas in my answer. To be more specific, please provide more details on your design, some screenshots could help.

Comment: Thank you. I think the approach that you mention works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an enum that would list all possible paths (or a static class with constants if you worry about maintainability, enums don't work well when compiled and then modified). Add a custom constructor to your form that would accept this enum as a parameter. When you instantiate a form, use that constructor. Basically replace all occurrences of `New QuickNoteForm()` with `New QuickNoteForm(yourEnumValue)`. For compatibility, add an `Unknown = 0` value to the enum, this way calling form's default constructor will work too, just not as useful.

If this approach is not practical (please provide more details on your application), you can also provide a context Control as parameter in your form's constructor. Then have code like  `If typeOf ctl Is Button AndAlso DirectCast(ctl, Button).Text = "Something" Then` and all sorts of crazy stuff. This promotes separation of concerns, i.e. the calling code does not need to know how to call and only pass itself as a parameter, but also makes your code harder to maintain, because you may end up with one giant know-it-all method which would connect all pieces together.

Comment: Your First Paragraph meets my requirement. thank you. its a good solution to track the callers via the enum.